# Proof of $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} \le 2 \times \sqrt{a+b}$?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I want to prove that  $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} \le 2 \times \sqrt{a+b}$, I had the idea to draw it:
[image]

Would it be enough to prove what I want to prove? If not, is there a way to be more precise by still using my method or should I abandon it and use a more "traditional" way?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no need for absolute values, as $a,b$ must both be nonnegative.

Comment: @vadim123 Thank you! I corrected the drawing.

Comment: have you thought about just squaring the inequality?

Comment: @user190080 I did, and it probably is easier, but since my first idea was to draw it I am wondering if this sort of proof makes any sense...

Comment: I think this is a nice "proof without words," but in most contexts where you actually need to demonstrate this to someone you should use "traditional" methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that $a,b$ are both nonnegative.
$$\sqrt{a}\le \sqrt{a+b}$$
$$\sqrt{b}\le \sqrt{a+b}$$
Now add the two.

Comment: Very elegant answer

Comment: Simplest approach possible (+unity) :-)

Comment: Nicely done. I personally would have squared both sides then use the AM-GM inequality (Which is much more complicated than this method).

Answer (score 2):

Not all problems have a nice geometrical interpretation. I think it is surely better to do this one in a purely algebraic way.

It would also be more convenient to assume a,b $\geq$ 0 for your problem.

Because a,b$\geq$0, then a$\leq$a+b and b$\leq$a+b, and because f(x)=$\sqrt{x}$ is increasing on $ R _ +$, then $\sqrt{a} \leq \sqrt{a+b}$ and $\sqrt{b} \leq \sqrt{a+b}.$
Finally, by adding the 2 inequalities, we get $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b} \leq 2*\sqrt{a+b}$

Comment: Please use $\rm\LaTeX$.